# How to detect whether is there any matches for regex?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this regex:

```
function test($str){
    return preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-',$str);
}
```

Here is a two examples:

**One:**

```
$str = "this is a str!";
echo test($str);
//=> this-is-a-str
```

As you see, that regex replaces white-spaced with `-` and removes `!`. Now need to get `true`, because that regex matches something.

**Two:**

```
$str = "this-is-a-str";
echo test($str);
//=> this-is-a-str
```

As you see, the output and input are identical, it means that regex doesn't replace nothing in this case. Now I need to get `false`.

---

Actually I'm trying to find a regex-checker :) ..! Something like `match()` in JavaScript. Is there a PHP function to do that?

Comment: Please check all parameters of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). If it is all you needed, the question is a really bad one. You could save a lot of time by checking [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: 5th parameter is a count of how many replacements were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a comparison with original string to figure if something has changed or not.

```
$str = "this is a str!";

var_dump(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z-]+~i', '-', $str) === $str);
//=> bool(false)

$str = "this-is-a-str";

var_dump(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z-]+~i', '-', $str) === $str);
//=> bool(true)
```

Additionally you should consider using this regex:

```
'~[^0-9a-z-]+~i'
```

To add hyphen in negated character class as you don't want to replace hyphen by itself.

Comment: Just one minor difference that I've added hyphen in negated character class

Comment: Also if regex is complex then executing two `preg` functions can be time consuming than string comparison

Answer (score 2):

To test if a pattern is matched you have to use `preg_match`:

```
function test( $str )
{
    $pattern = '~[^0-9a-z]+~i';
    if( preg_match( $pattern, $str ) )
    {
         return preg_replace( $pattern, '-', $str );
    }
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Edit:

You can also use `count` parameter to check the replacement:

```
function test( $str )
{
    $pattern = '~[^0-9a-z]+~i';
    $retval = preg_replace( $pattern, '-', $str, -1, $count );
    if( $count ) return $retval;
    else         return FALSE;
}
```

`$count` parameter return the number of replacements.

---

- Read more about [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- Read more about [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @stack please read update answer: second solution is better, and modify pattern as anubhava answer, otherwise will not return false if original string contains '-'

Comment: Yeah ... your second approach seems better. Thank you

Comment: May you please tell me what is `-1` in this `preg_replace( $pattern, '-', $str, -1, $count )`

Comment: @stack You can read the [documentatio](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), sometime is faster than asking! BTW, it means _no-limit_. If you set it to 1, only 1 replacement will be performed, 2=only two, etc...